# Android toolbar in DrawerLayout takes up entire view

Tags: android, toolbar

Here is the activity I'm trying to put the toolbar in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/activity_game_drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_game_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I've tried solutions from many other posts about this issue, but none have worked so far.  I've even tried starting an entirely new project with nothing but the one activity with the toolbar and have the same issue.

You can view the entire project at: https://github.com/NikKosse/Text-Game

Let me know if you need any more information from me!

Comment: This is because you have set height of toolbar to `match_parent` just change the line to `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"`

Comment: I tried that, and `wrap_content` as someone else suggested, but neither have worked.

Comment: What do you want to show using that xml just plain toolbar with navigation drawer on left? I guess that's not what you are trying to achieve,right?

Comment: I pulled your git repo and everything seems to be working fine...toolbar takes up actionBarSize height[not entire screen height]..the reason you are seeing empty screen below the toolbar is because the `content_game.xml` is blank with no elements added..

Comment: @Droidwala Are you not seeing the text "GameActivity" in the center of the screen?  I set the background color of the toolbar to green to show that it is taking up the full screen: http://i.imgur.com/iCwoIUW.png

Comment: No, i see text "GameActivity" only on toolbar at the top and not on entire screen..

Comment: @Droidwala I just realized that I haven't pushed my changes to GitHub yet, which is why you're seeing the working version.  But that version is using an action bar instead of a toolbar, and apparently best practice is to use toolbar instead.  I've pushed the broken toolbar to GitHub so if you pull it again you'll see the problem.

Comment: I pulled up the version in which you had `app_bar_game.xml` in your layout folder and inside `activity_game.xml` you had following lines...` `<include layout="@layout/app_bar_game" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>`                                                       
                                                                                                             The one with commit msg - `finished most of the game drawer UI`

Comment: That is the correct approach to the problem.Pull back to that commit and all you have to do now is populate your game screen content using `content_game.xml` file.. And kindly note that version(commit:68c4564)  is not using actionbar anywhere as stated in your earlier comment ,you are using toolbar only..

Comment: @Droidwala ok, thanks!  Now, do you know where I need to go to find and edit the text that shows up on that toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your `xml` very closely..

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" //this part

android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
...
```

You have `android:layout_height` with `match_parent` for your `DrawerLayout` - which means take up all available space ...

You're doing the same with `Toolbar` telling it to take up all the space available in your `DrawerLayout`, so it takes up all the space taken by your `DrawerLayout` minus padding.

Remove, please,  the `match_parent` from your `toolbar` and make it `wrap_content` or with fixed height.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" // or 50dp
 ...
```

Comment: @Elitz perhabs he could instead of doing wrap_content(that works fine) just make  set the  ?android:attr/actionBarSize. I prefer this option because depending on the device screen size it will know how what does actionBarSize means for that device and give it a correct height

Comment: I tried both `wrap_content` and `?attr/actionBarSize`, neither of which solved my problem.  Any other ideas?